# How to associate form with a `bootstrap_field` outside that form?

Tags: python, django, forms, bootstrap-5

Given this field `{% bootstrap_field form.photo %}` which is a `forms.ImageField` and the form after, I need to associate the field with the form in a way that when the form is submitted, I get the value in `form.photo`.

```
<div class="row container h-100">
    <div class="col-xl-4">
        <div class="card mb-4 mb-xl-0">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <img style="max-width: 50%" alt="Avatar" class="img-account-profile rounded-circle mb-2"
                     src={{ request.user.profile.photo.url }}>
                {% bootstrap_field form.photo %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col h-100">
        <div class="card shadow-lg">
            <div class="card-body p-5">
                <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="row">
                 <span class="col">
                 {% bootstrap_field form.first_name %}
                 </span>
                        <span class="col">
                 {% bootstrap_field form.last_name %}
                 </span>
                        <button class="btn btn-success col">Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently if a photo is uploaded, it won't show up in the form response because it's not included within `<form></form>`. I need it to be outside the form because the locations of the form fields and the photo are different.

One way to do so is to wrap both cards inside the form tags. Is this the best way to do it or is there a simpler way like specifying `{% bootstrap_field my_field form=my_form %}`